# What happens if I do not specify a Stale paramter on my view?

Tags: couchdb

I have a couchdb view. I add a document. I query my view (whose map fn includes the document that was just added).

I know that the specs say that if I query my view with Stale=ok then I will get a result that does not include my new document. I also know that if I query my view with Stale=update_after then I will get a result that does not include my document - but if I call my view a second time (after a delay that allows enough processing time for the view) then I will get a result with my document.

But, the documentation is not clear on what happens when I do not specify the Stale paramter.

Will:
 a) I get a stale view without my document?
 b) Will the view update and then the result including my document occur?

If the answer is b) and there are X (where X is a very large number) documents pending, will my view still update before returning results or will it time out? or will it switch it's behaviour to a stale=update_after or stale=ok?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not specifying `stale`, you are getting the default behavior which is to update the view before sending you a result. (ie: stale results is not the default, hence the additional option)

Comment: Thank you for confirming what I thought was the case, except, I hadn't seen that explicitly in the documentation.